# LibraryFunctionLoad not recognizing datatype

Tags: librarylink

I am trying to use [`LibraryFunctionLoad`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LibraryFunctionLoad.html) with a function that relies on a derived type that is defined within the library. I've loaded the library prior to calling `LibraryFunctionLoad`.

`LibraryFunctionLoad` produces the error:

> ```
> libraryFunctionLoad::btype : Invalid type and/or rank specification in myDataType
> ```

Where `myDataType` is the derived type defined in the library.

Comment: Adding a minimal *Mathematica* code example that produces this error will presumable increase the probability of getting a good answer.

Comment: You should not use `LibraryLoad` before using `LibraryFunctionLoad`. It is only for loading dependencies, not for loading the library itself.  This cannot be answered without seeing you `LibraryFunctionLoad` call.  If you are still interested in an answer, please provide that.